# Transport layer end-to-end rate control in ns-3

Tags: ns-3

I am looking for an end-to-end rate control for an application that uses UDP. What can I use/implement for that?

I couldn't find any of the RTP and DCCP implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linux kernel implementation of DCCP through [DCE](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/dce/manual/html/intro.html).